# Closure of Off Topic Questions

Tags: feature-request, off-topic

There seems to be a few people, including myself, wondering why their question got closed as off topic, and what to do next to get their questions answered. I feel that the `Closed as off topic` message isnt very helpful to the person asking the question, its almost as if they are having a door slammed in their face for not asking the right question in the right place.

To this end, I would like to suggest that when a question gets closed as Off Topic and if this question is more appropriately asked elsewhere on SE then the user should at least be alerted to this.

For example, the message could say something like

```
Closed as off topic by <list of users>
Try asking this question here: <more appropriate site>
```

Or if there is nowhere on SE specific for that question, at least list some kind of reason why this question has been listed as off topic. I feel like this would help to educate new users and help to redirect users from more popular SE sites like StackOverflow towards more appropriate but lesser known SE sites.

Just a suggestion :)

Answer (score 7):

Usually *there is no suitable site* for it to be asked on.

If there *is* such a site and your question quality is good enough, the moderators will migrate it for you; us non-mods are given a choice of migration targets (the most popular ones), and we can flag a post to indicate that it might be migrated to any of the other SE sites if it is suitable.

This is not something we want to automate any further; if people don't read the FAQ of a site to see if something is on-topic to start with, then usually there are other things wrong with a post. The close reason includes a pointer to the FAQ of the site, and we do *expect* you to put in a little research yourself. Is it that hard to look for the correct site up-front?